# How do I change the type of elements of a 2D list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that I get by opening a txt file. That list is a 2D list which looks like:

```
[['25 1 100.5 2 300'], ['50 3 125.5 4 85']]
```

I want the sublists to not be strings but be integers (when the position is uneven in the list) and floats (when the position is even in the list). For instance, I want the list to look like:

```
[[25.0, 1, 100.5, 2, 300.0], [50.0, 3, 125.5, 4, 85.0]]
```

So far, I have tried

```
list = [['25 1 100.5 2 300'], ['50 3 125.5 4 85']]
for x in list:
    str_to_num = x.split()
```

And that's where I don't know how to separate which element will become a float and which will become an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you like a one-liner?

```
In [27]: ll = [['25 1 100.5 2 300'], ['50 3 125.5 4 85']]
In [28]: [[(int(x) if i%2 else float(x)) for i,x in 
               enumerate(l[0].split())] for l in ll]
Out[28]: [[25.0, 1, 100.5, 2, 300.0], [50.0, 3, 125.5, 4, 85.0]]
```

If you aren't picky about the int/float distinction, this will do:

```
In [32]: [[float(x) for x in l[0].split()] for l in ll]
Out[32]: [[25.0, 1.0, 100.5, 2.0, 300.0], [50.0, 3.0, 125.5, 4.0, 85.0]]
```

For many numeric operations it isn't important whether the value is float `1.0` or integer `1`.

Another way to distinguish between int and floats is if `int(astr)` raises an error (`int('1')` v `int('1.23')`)

To use that I have to define a little function:

```
In [44]: def foo(astr):
    try:
        return int(astr)
    except ValueError:
        return float(astr)
   ....:     
In [45]: [[foo(x) for x in l[0].split()] for l in ll]
Out[45]: [[25, 1, 100.5, 2, 300], [50, 3, 125.5, 4, 85]]
```

In this case only the middle strings appear as floats.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [['25 1 100.5 2 300'], ['50 3 125.5 4 85']]
new_list = []
for x in list:
  new_list.append([float(y) for y in x[0].split(" ")])
```

This will convert all the numbers to floats. Of course it is assuming that you have only one string with numbers per list.

Good luck.

Comment: You could just use `x[0].split()` and it would be better in the sense that it would handle strings multiple spaces between the numbers too.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your x.split() is trying to split a list rather than a string (note that ['25 1 100.5 2 300'] is a list with one element in it, which is the string '25 1 100.5 2 300'). If the sub lists are always going to have exactly one such string you could fix your code by using x[0].split() instead.

This is a combined corrected edit that presumes you want an int when you can get it or a float:

```
def to_number(num_str):
    try:
       return_value = int(num_str)
    except ValueError:
       return_value = float(num_str)
    return return_value

old_list = [['25 1 100.5 2 300'], ['50 3 125.5 4 85']]
new_list = []
for x in old_list:
   num_strs = x[0].split()
   new_list.append([to_number(_) for _ in num_strs])
```

Comment: Actually though I would avoid using the word "list" as the name of your list, since it has a special meaning...and I forgot to cast the results as ints or floats...

Comment: How would you cast to ints and floats?

Comment: added this to answer. Just use the function instead of float() in the other code.

Comment: `float(x[0].split())` is wrong because `float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`.